# Android How Do I Place ICON (ie Search Icon) inside content area of EditText or AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

Thats it how do I place an icon inside text area as background of EditText or AutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 3):

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/somedrawable"
```

Comment: this works only if you need a very simple relationship between the icon and the edit text. see my answer for how to solve this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
android:backgroud="@drawable/somedrawable"
```

from your XML layout, or

```
View.setBackgroundResource(int resId)
```

from your activity code. this works for most View types including composites.

If you need to position the icon relative to the edit text, you should put both of them (the edit text, and an image view for the icon) inside a layout view, such as a relative layout. This allows you to position them with respect to each other however you like. Explaining how relative layout works is outside the scope of what can be covered here. Just Google for it and you'll find lots of good example.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Selvin's answer may also work for you (android:drawableRight=...). This is simpler, but obviously less flexible than putting the elements in a layout.

Comment: well I need to place it exactly at the right end of the editable part of the EditText.  So I need it to be under the white area to the end.  Not sure if just setting the background is going to do?

Comment: I need to know how to position it at the end of the edit box. Its just the search icon.  Thanks

Comment: your question asked "... as a background", so that's what i answered. i'll update my answer.

Comment: there is no need for relative layouts ... see my answer :)